# Doublespacing is moving my page number

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, line-spacing, setspace

I'm using the KOMA-Script report `scrreprt` to typeset my PhD thesis and the graduate school requires that the main text be double spaced and that the page number be in the top right. When I enable double spacing the page number moves down a little bit. How can I solve this?

Here is a MWE that reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%this code clears the header/footer
\clearscrheadfoot
%then puts the page number in the top right
\rohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\chapter{ch1}
hello
\chapter{ch2}
\doublespacing
hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `\setstretch{1}` to the header seems to help:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\headfont{\setstretch{1}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Your solution didn't work when I tried to apply it to the MWE (updated with newer packages), but this one did: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367660/222293

Comment: @Lucas Thanks for the hint. The answer was written for package `scrpage2`. In the meantime, KOMA-script has changed. Package `scrpage2` was removed and package `scrlayer-scrpage` was added as incompatible replacement.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed yours worked with the older packages. I just wanted to point people toward a solution for the newer packages. Cheers