# setspace: double spacing messes the predefined position of page number

Tags: koma-script, line-spacing, geometry, setspace, scrlayer-scrpage

Referring to [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/322024/2288), I was helped to know how to control the page number position, however, when using `\doublespacing`, the position is messed up as shown below.

How can I keep the same layout including the page number position regardless the line spacing?

---

### Single spacing

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper,
top=2cm,
bottom=1cm,
includefoot,
left=4cm,
right=2cm,
footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\rofoot*{\pagemark}
\cofoot*{}
\pagestyle{plain.scrheadings}
\usepackage{lipsum,setspace} 

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Chapter Title}
    \singlespacing
    \lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Double spacing

```
\begin{document}

    \chapter{Chapter Title}
    \doublespacing
    \lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76382/doublespacing-is-moving-my-page-number

Comment: Your image corresponds to a page number in the header and your code  says it should be in the footer. So?

Comment: @Bernard The number is in the footer, and the red lines in my images are referring to the offsets from the right and bottom margins.

Comment: @samcarter Many thanks for your helpful links, could you please post it as an answer to accept it?

Comment: @samcarter I am sorry, but adding `\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\footfont{\setstretch{1}}
\makeatother` before `\begin{document}` didn't solve my problem when I test it now. I got [this ouput](http://imgur.com/D4RK1wR).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get single spaced header and footer on all pages where a layer page style is used, add

```
\KOMAoptions{onpsinit={\linespread{1}\selectfont}}
```

to your preamble.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper,
top=2cm,
bottom=1cm,
includefoot,
left=4cm,
right=2cm,
footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[
  footsepline,plainfootsepline,% only to show the position of the footer
  footbotline,plainfootbotline% only to show the position of the footer
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\KOMAoptions{onpsinit={\linespread{1}\selectfont}}% <- added
\rofoot*{\pagemark}
\cofoot*{}
\pagestyle{plain.scrheadings}
\usepackage{lipsum,setspace}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter Title}
    \singlespacing
    \lipsum[1-19]
    \chapter{Chapter Title}
    \doublespacing
    \lipsum[1-19]
\end{document}
```